# How to show data in tool tip on item template in datalist in asp.net C#?

Tags: asp.net, tooltip, datalist

I want to show some data in tool tip on mouse hover. I am using datalist in asp.net. How can I show dynamic data in tool tip.The data will be based on database tables. This is the code for my datalist and I want tool tip to be shown on item template. The tooltip data will contain 3 items viz available quantity,on hand quantity and on order quantity.

EDIT: I tried ways provided in answer of this question but they are not working.
Is there any way that I can do the same using JQuery and web service? If yes then please guide me the proper way...

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlvProductSpecification" runat="server" RepeatColumns="10" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="16px"
                                            Font-Size="Smaller" OnItemCommand="dlvProductSpecification_ItemCommand" OnItemCreated="dlvProductSpecification_ItemCreated"
                                            OnItemDataBound="dlvProductSpecification_ItemDataBound">
                                            <ItemStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center">  </HeaderStyle>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <table class="header_dl">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            SPECIFICATION HEADER
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <%--<table style="text-align: center;">--%>
                                                <table class="style_dl" onmouseover="showtooltip()" onmouseout="hidetooltip()">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="style_dl_td">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblReferenceNo" CssClass="labeltitle_dl" runat="server"><%# Eval("ReferenceNo")%></asp:Label>
                                                            <br />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%# Eval("Specification")%></asp:Label>
                                                            <br />
                                                            <br />
                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSpecificationID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ProductSpecificationID")%>' />
                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSpecification" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Specification")%>' />
                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnReferenceNo" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ReferenceNo")%>' />
                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnGTIN" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("GTIN")%>' />
                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAvailableQty" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("AvailableQty")%>' />
                                                            <asp:Button ID="btnAddQty" runat="server" CommandName="GetData" Text="Add" /><br />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on ItemDataBound event. Try this:

```
protected void dlvProductSpecification_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||e.Item.ItemType== ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            e.Item.ToolTip = "Tool Tip";
        }
    }
```

Comment: In a grid view, tootltip can be added like this at RowDataBound event. Hope it helps you.                                         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
                    {
                        cell.Attributes.Add("title", "Tool tip. ");
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Item templates' Label put a toolTip property and bind it like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Specification") %>'><%# Eval("Specification")%></asp:Label>
```

hope it works.